# How to Store a stylesheet reference defined in a XAML in a separate Class to be used in any XAML Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML **MyXamlStyleSheet.xaml** where I define the style of a Button and Various other Controls. 
I also have a C# class **MyButtonClass : Button** that I defined to intercept the basic Button class and declare any custom functionality that I want to give it.

In the XAML Window where I want to use  I have declared a **xmlns:lc** with the source pointing to the C# class **MyButtonClass**.

What I want to do is that when I declare this custom button

```
<lc:MyButtonClass .../>
```

I have a Reference to the Style defined in **MyXamlStyleSheet** that is stored in **MyButtonClass** so that I can access it from the XAML Window.

What would I write in the class and in the xaml declaration?

```
<lc:MyButtonClass Style="{StaticResource ???"..../>
```

Until now I have used **MergedDictionaries** to reference the XAML style sheet directly. However I want to do it using this different path.

Comment: You don't actually want to define a default Style for MyButtonClass?

Comment: No I want to be able to customize it and see that customization reflected in my entire application, spanning about 20 windows.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to set the Style property of the Button to a Style whose x:Key is defined in a property of the custom Button? Or why can't you just set the Style using the StaticResource markup extension <lc:MyButtonClass Style="{StaticResource theKeyOfTheStyle}" />?

Comment: That´s a way to setting the style directly from a Dictionary. What I mean to do is to have a separate Folder in which every control has its class and every class has a Reference to the Dictionary and the specific key. That way when I use my control class through the xmlns tag I can specify its default style from my style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. It´s the same as Merging a Dictionary to your XAML Window int the **Window.Resources** section. From your class you instantiate a ResourceDictionary with the correct path and Merge that dictionary to the Dictionary of the Button class.

```
namespace YourNamespace
{

    public class MyCustomButton : Button
    {

        public MyCostumButton()
        {

            ResourceDictionary res = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/Directory/StyleDirectory.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
            if (res == null)
                return;
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(res);
            Style = (Style)FindResource("Name of the x:Key your gave your style");
        }
    }
}
```

This let´s you write an entire library of standarized controls in a Folder, where each control has a C# class assigned to it. So if you have many implementations of the same control you can always define the most basic behaviour and look in the XAML file that the class is referencing.